# pgAdmin-III - Option to load a favorite automatically when opening query window

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

pgAdmin-III - Query window option

Does pgAdmin-III has any option to load a default favorite file automatically when opening new query window? This would be much useful to have commit/rollback statements by default when executing random sql statements.

Example:

```
BEGIN;
SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
-- Todo Queries
-- Ex. UPDATE users SET firstname = 'new first name' WHERE lastname = 'lastname';


-- Either one below
-- COMMIT;
-- ROLLBACK TO my_savepoint;
```

I want this always to be loaded when opening a new query window from pgAdmin-III.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct option, but I use command line option to load my favorite sql automatically at starting pgAdmin.

for exmaple in windows :
start "" "...../pgAdmin3.exe" -q -f "favorite.sql"

-q options means that you launch query tool only.
-f "filepath" instructs sql file automatically opened in query tool editor.

detail of options are
http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/commandline.html